# ActionBar not showing on android < 5.0

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design

I switched from ABS to AppCompat and Material theme(for api 21 only)

```
<!--manifest: -->
<application
        android:theme="@style/AppStyle"

<-- values folder -->
<style name="AppStyle" parent="@style/AudioRecTheme">
<style name="AudioRecTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

<!-- values-v21 folder-->
<style name="AudioRecTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light">
```

My activity:

```
public class AudioRecActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

**The action bar is showing only in Android 5.0, but missing otherwise.**

Comment: how are you apply style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, either use `appcompat-v7` **or** use built-in themes, not both for the same activity. Here, you are trying to use `Theme.AppCompat.Light` in some cases and `Theme.Material.Light` in others, which is not only unnecessary but AFAIK will not work. If you are going to use `Theme.AppCompat.Light`, do so for all API levels.

Second, if you are going to use `appcompat-v7` and `Theme.AppCompat.Light`, you need to inherit from `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: I use appcompat-v7, but I want the theme to inherit native Material  style when v21.

Comment: If I inherit ActionBarActivity, it will crash on 5.0 since I use Material theme for Lollipop

Comment: @AlexandruCircus: Then create two separate activities. You cannot have one activity both inherit from `ActionBarActivity` and not inherit from `ActionBarActivity`. You need `ActionBarActivity` for `appcompat-v7`, and as you note you cannot use `ActionBarActivity` for `Theme.Material.*`.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare! I will use 2 separate activities

Comment: The only problem is that this activity is the launcher, so it is a little complicated to use 2 activities...

Comment: There is a difference bwtween AppCompat and Material for api 21? Or AppCompat fully supports Material and also backwards compat?

Comment: @AlexandruCircus: The point behind the current version of `appcompat-v7` is to offer a look that closely resembles `Theme.Material`, at least for the action bar itself. "Closely resembles" != "identical", and so there are minor visual differences, but not so much that a casual examiner will notice. For example, IIRC, the font on `Theme.AppCompat` for the action bar title is a bit smaller.

Comment: Thanks! I think I will use AppCompat on all API levels as you suggested above.